# Problems with controller mapping in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

There are similar topics, but they all use xml configuration files. The reason why I'm writing this question is that I'm using annotations.

I experience problems running my app:

- getting “WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No
  mapping found for HTTP request with URI …” when trying to setup
  Spring servlet
- getting error 404 when trying to run it on server

Here is my code (package and imports are skipped):

1) initializer

```
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = 
            new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);

        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = 
            servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
            servlet.addMapping("/");
            servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        }
    }
```

2) app config

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("ua.kiev.prog")
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManager() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("AdvJPA");
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public AdvDAO advDAO() {
        return new AdvDAOImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    }
}
```

3) controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Advertisement")
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private AdvDAO advDAO;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView listAdvs() {
        return new ModelAndView("index", "advs", advDAO.list());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add_page", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPage(Model model) {
        return "add_page";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView search(@RequestParam(value="pattern") String pattern) {
        return new ModelAndView("index", "advs", advDAO.list(pattern));
    }

// more code goes here
}
```

The controller is mapped to /Advertisement, so app should be available at URL  localhost:8080/Advertisement/ but it isn't. When I change mapping in annotation to "/" - it becomes available at localhost:8080/Advertisement/. How can it be? 
And when I change it back to "/Advertisement" - the same probleb accurs (error 404 and exception "No mapping found for HTTP request with URI …")

So, where I've made a mistake in my code?
Or maybe the problem is in Eclipse/TomCat/Maven?

Source - https://github.com/KostyantynPanchenko/prog.kiev.ua.lesson09.adv

Comment: What is the context path of your application? Do you deploy it as the ROOT war?

Comment: The context path is "/", and I'm just running it via Eclipse (Run as -> Run on server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change mapping

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private AdvDAO advDAO;

    @RequestMapping("/Advertisement")
    public ModelAndView listAdvs() {
        return new ModelAndView("index", "advs", advDAO.list());
    }
```

The mistake that a mapper used the value from the annotation to match the request URL, and it can't match the last slash. Note, it should not happen in the above code.

Comment: ok, if I change to @RequestMapping("/") app is available at  localhost:8080/Advertisement/ but the question remains why at localhost:8080/Advertisement/ and not localhost:8080/?

Comment: Roman C, could you, please, explain why with @RequestMapping("/") app is still available at localhost:8080/Advertisement/ ?

Comment: this mapping is for all class methods that has a mapping annotation.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that I also should change mapping for all other methods to "/Advertisement/..", for example instead of "/add" - > "/Advertisement/add"

Comment: It's up to you but then you can modify other methods because you have used "/" on the class.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running the application? Atleast in tomcat each deployed application is served from specific context path. Context path is determined from the base file name, more on that [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html).

So if you're deploying *Advertisement.war* all requests to the app will be served from localhost:8080/Advertisement/ even though you're declaring the DispatcherServlet and Controller to `/`

Comment: No, OP said he's using root context path.